# HTML progress bar goal checkpoints

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have created this progress bar and I wanted to show checkpoint locations on it. Here is what it currently looks like and how I got it that way.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="padding-top: 150px;">
  <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; margin-top: -37px;">
    <span style="margin-left: 50.526315789474%; position: absolute;">$4800<br>|</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 73.684210526316%; position: absolute;">$7000<br>|</span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
      $4275 / $9500
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking for is a better way to do this.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by checkpoints?  Sounds to me like you just need some CSS on the progress value.

Comment: @Brad the values 4800 and 7000 above the progress bar